# How to display total count on top of the stacked bar chart

Tags: d3.js, c3.js

[image]

Hi All i tired to display total in to top of the d3  c3 chart like attached image

Answer (score 3):

You will need:

- [data.labels.format](http://c3js.org/reference.html#data-labels-format)
- [legend.item.onclick](http://c3js.org/reference.html#legend-item-onclick)
- [data.order](http://c3js.org/reference.html#data-order)
- [chart.data.shown](http://c3js.org/reference.html#api-data-shown)
- [chart.toggle](http://c3js.org/reference.html#api-toggle)

Showing only top label is simple: just check current visible labels and find the last:

```
function showLastLabel()
{
    var shown = chart.data.shown().map(function(item){ return item.id }) // get visible ids: ['data1', 'data2', ...]
    var last = (shown[shown.length - 1])
    d3.select('.c3-chart-texts').selectAll('.c3-target').style('display', 'none') // hide all
    d3.select('.c3-chart-texts').selectAll('.c3-target-' + last).style('display', 'block') // show last
}
```

Important thing is to disable stack reordering (c3 does this by default) because it breaks logic described above.

```
order: null,
```

Then, calculating total top label needs additional check for visibility:

```
labels: {
    format: function(v, id, i, j)
    {
        if (isNaN(totals[i])) totals[i] = 0

        // sum only visible
        if (chart)
        {
            var shown = chart.data.shown().map(function(item){ return item.id })
            if (shown.indexOf(id) != -1) totals[i] += v
        }
        else
        {
            totals[i] += v
        }

        return totals[i]
    }
},
```

At last we update labels' visibility when clicking on legend items:

```
legend: {
  item: {
    onclick: function (id) { 
        chart.toggle([id]) // keep default functionality
        showLastLabel()
    }
  }
},
```

**See full example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Dimmy/d5sxjng2/6/)**

Comment: Thanks, But it will display the number like each color, not total count in the top. I need to total value display in top in the each bar.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. This is expected answer. while placing this code into my code, i came to know one more issue like when ever i  deselected the group in the chart the count is added twice, say for example i have 6 groups(A,B,C,D,E,F) and its shows 6 color in the bar. if i De-selelcted the group A then the total could should be reduce right, but it happening. this will increasing the count....   If there is any alternative way, that is really helpful for me.

Comment: Good point, totals should always be reset when redrawing chart. This can be done in onrendered callback, see update. But deselecting data groups is more complicated case, so totals' calculation needs some adjustment. I'll try to figure out how, stay tuned :)

Comment: Thank you... i am waiting for you response... :)

Comment: See updated answer and fiddle. I also advise you to dig into c3-reference links above - c3 actually is a very flexible lib and creating your custom solutions is not as hard as it seems. Good luck!